# Creating file or folder showing drwxr-x--- 2 root bin

Tags: linux, files, permissions, binary

I am not sure why i get this `drwxr-x--- 2 root bin` every time I create a new file or folder on an NFS share. Earlier I used to get `drwxrwxrwx 2 root root`.

```
id root
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)

umask
0027
```

Can someone help me find the root cause for this issue?

Comment: What is the output of the command `id root`?

Comment: # id root
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)

Comment: Where (in what directory) are you trying to create one of these problematic directories? What are the permissions (ownerships) of the parent? What filesystem type are you using? What's the output of `umask`?

Comment: # umask
0027 , this is NFS mount share i am creating the file/folder under that.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/750202/edit) to add this information. Make it easy to read - as if you'd written it in the original question

Comment: yes i am sure, drwxr-x--- 2 root bin   152 Jun 29 11:01 folder1 , -rw-r----- 1 root bin     0 Jun 27 16:26 test3.txt

Comment: An umask of `0027` would give exactly those permissions for a usual (non-private) directory. That's what it does, the value masks out group write permissions and others' all permissions

Comment: as mentioned earlier, i was getting root root on the same umask but now getting root bin dont understand why. @ilkkachu

Comment: The `umask` value has to be the culprit. Try `umask 0000; mkdir foo`  and see what happens. I would not suggest a world-writable directory on any multi-user or multi-service system as that can lead to a multitude of problems.

Comment: "_I was getting `root root` […] but now getting `root bin`_" - I'd say the NFS Server is culprit here